# laravel 5.2 serve command unexpected character coming

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have developed project and i need to serve using (php artisan serve )command .

when am using this command it serves but before that it displays character (a) in command line pls find the image for  better understanding ..and tat  (a) is coming on the browser page also....[image]

[image]